# How to change color of directory suggestions in ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-zsh 
Problem: want to change the background color of suggested directories

How to reproduce the problem:
run `ls` then type `vim <tab>` (in zsh)

Yellow background color -> to any other color

I have tried using https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/ to test colors but didn't work.

[image: `]

Currently have this in my .zshrc
`_ls_colors="di=1;36:ln=35:so=32:pi=33:ex=31:bd=34;46:cd=34;43:su=30;41:sg=30;46:tw=30;42:ow=30;43"`  
`zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors "${(s.:.)_ls_colors}"`

Comment: What do you mean with "suggested directories"?

Comment: And perhaps you could add a screenshot of your entire terminal? I'm not sure what I'm looking at in the tightly cropped image you posted.

Comment: @MarlonRichert suggested directories when you type a character, click tab and it gives you a suggestion of available directories? and the screenshot is an example of suggested directories "build/.../node_modules" The background is yellow I want to change it to another color.

Comment: Can you share your `~/.zshrc` file?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Jairo Molina for the suggestion - this worked for me in my `.zshrc`:

```
# remove ls highlight color
_ls_colors=":ow=01;33" 
zstyle ':completion:*:default' list-colors "${(s.:.)_ls_colors}"
LS_COLORS+=$_ls_colors
```

which renders this:
[image]

vs this nastiness:
[image]

this also works for `ls` whereas your above bit did not
[image]